# How to set the background of a custom shaped ImageButton in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In a recyclerView I have list of imageButtons with a custom shape applied as the background of all ImageButtons. Each ImageButton currently has a solid color from a colorlist: `colors[]`

**This is how it looks right now:**

[image]

I want to put a icon.png in the place of index 0 (brown colored button) instead of the solid color. So far I have used many days of trying to find a solution myself but without any succses.

Here is all relevant code:

**This is the code in the recyclerView adapter that sets the colors:**

```
Resources resources = App.getAppContext().getResources();
String colors[] = resources.getStringArray(R.array.backgroundcolors);

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {


    Drawable drawable = holder.colorButton.getBackground();

    //This is here where each ImageButton gets a color from the colorlist colors[]

    if (drawable instanceof GradientDrawable) {
        GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable) drawable.getCurrent();
        gd.setColor(Color.parseColor(colors[position]));

        //This does nothing
    } else if (drawable instanceof RippleDrawable) {
        RippleDrawable rd = (RippleDrawable) drawable;
        int color = Color.parseColor(colors[position]);
        rd.setColor(newColorStateList(color));
    }
}
```

**The colorStatList code for each imageButton:**

```
 private static ColorStateList newColorStateList(int color) {
    int[][] states = new int[][]{

            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
            new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
    };

    int[] colors = new int[]{
            color, color
    };
    return new ColorStateList(states, colors);
}
```

**My Custom button for the recyclerView Adapter:**

```
public class ColorButton{

private ImageButton button;
private String color;
public static List<ColorButton> colorButtonList;


public ColorButton(ImageButton button, String color) {
    this.button = button;
    this.color = color;
}

static ColorButton colorButton = new ColorButton(new ImageButton(App.getAppContext()), null);

public static List<ColorButton> initColorButtons(){
    colorButtonList = new ArrayList<>();

    Resources resources = App.getAppContext().getResources();
    String colors[] = resources.getStringArray(R.array.backgroundcolors);


    for(int i=0; i<colors.length; i++){

        colorButtonList.add(new ColorButton(new ImageButton(App.getAppContext()), colors[i]));
    }

    return colorButtonList;
}
```

You may wonder why I have `String color;`
This is for setting the background color of my app when the user clicks on a colorbutton:`mEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor((mColorButtons.get(position).getColor())));`

Comment: If you're using the ImageButton, you have two properties in the xml: the `background` - apply your own shape, but put the color in that shape to transparent (alpha=0), and the `src` property -> here you can set the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) { 
if(position ==0){
holder.colorButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.colorpicker2);
}
else
{
GradientDrawable gd = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bbshape);
gd.setColor(Color.parseColor(colors[position]));
holder.colorButton.setBackGroundDrawable(gd);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!